# How to display multiple values in on column using postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

Given the following table structure:

---

**table1**

```
first | pkey <- column names
val1  | 1
```

---

**table2**

```
second | fkey <- column names
val2   | 1
val3   | 1
val4   | 1
```

---

I would like some output like the following:

```
first | second <- column names
val1 | val2, val3, val4
```

I have tried:

```
select table1.first, (select table2.second where table1.pkey=table2.fkey)
from table1 join on table2 where table1.pkey=table2.fkey;
```

Something about that looks wrong, so I get the following:

```
more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

I also tried

```
select table1.first, (select table2.second where table1.pkey=table2.fkey)
from table1, table2;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following using `string_agg`. Here is the [DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9SXoECymBJzWtLwpG8Ynfg/0)

```
select
    first,
    string_agg(second, ',') as second
from table1 t1
join table2 t2
on t1.pkey = t2.fkey 
group by
    first
```

Output

```
*----------------------*
| first  second        | 
*----------------------*
| val1  val2,val3,val4 |
*----------------------*
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you so much.  I take it there is no way to do this without using a built in sql function or writing a custom sql function?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend aggregating the second column as an array rather than a string:

```
select t1.first, array_agg(t2.second)
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t1.pkey = t2.fkey
group by first
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. Depending on the result you want to get there are three options:

```
select
    table1.first,
    (select string_agg(table2.second, ', ') from table2 where table1.pkey=table2.fkey)
from table1;
```

to get a plain text value, or

```
select
    table1.first,
    (select array_agg(table2.second) from table2 where table1.pkey=table2.fkey),
    array(select table2.second from table2 where table1.pkey=table2.fkey)
from table1;
```

to get an array of values (in two syntactic ways), or

```
select
    table1.first,
    (select json_agg(table2.second) from table2 where table1.pkey=table2.fkey)
from table1;
```

to get JSON array.

Note that I moved `table2` completely to the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

When I posted this question, I remember I had inadvertently done what was asked a while ago.  But I could not remember how.  Turns out this might be an easier way to do this.

```
select table1.first, table2 as second
from table1 join table2 on table1.pkey=table2.fkey;
```

Seems as though selecting the table in a join, puts the whole row of table returned in one column named the table name.  Then you can use `as` to name the column the name you want.